# Python regular expression zero or more occurrences

Tags: python, regex, match

`I can\'?t (.*)`

My regex is of the above form. But my match object doesn't match if the string given to it ends after  `t`

`re.compile(r'I can\'?t (.*)').match(str)`

If str = "I cant", it doesn't work. But if str = "I can't use", it works (match returns something).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You left a mandatory space after the `t`. Remove it and you'll be fine:

```
I can\'?t(.*)
```

Also note that the brackets are only useful if you want to use the content of the first capturing group, if not you can safely remove them.

Comment: @laike9m: Glad I could help. If an answer completely solved your issue remember to mark it as accepted to close the question, and you're good to go.

Comment: @laike9m: Wooops, that's right :) Thanks for the support then I guess!

Answer (score 0):

For that you can do:

`re.compile(r'I can\'?t.*').match(str)`

This will match either `"I can't"` with some other text following or just `"I can't"`

Comment: Here the alternation is irrelevant: `.*` will always match, even if it's an empty string. By putting it as the first choice you are ensuring that `$` will never be used.